# Node async await code writing style which one is good and optimized

Tags: node.js, express, async-await

I used to write code for async-await in (Style 1), other dev suggested me to write in (Style 2).

Can someone please explain to me what is the difference between both styles, **for me it seems the same.**

### Code Style 1:

```
const fixtures = await fixtureModel.fetchAll();
const team = await teamModel.fetch(teamId);
```

### Code Style 2:

```
const fixturesPromise = fixtureModel.fetchAll();
const teamPromise = teamModel.fetch(teamId);

const fixtures = await fixturesPromise;
const team = await teamPromise;
```

Comment: In this case really no quantifiable difference. 2nd code style is usable or might make sense when used with `Promise.all[fixturesPromise,teamPromise]`.

Comment: Did you ask the other dev why? Do you agree with those reasons?

Comment: @jonrsharpe he told me that both are not dependent on each other so first create promise then call.

Comment: ...and do you think that reasoning makes sense?

Comment: @jonrsharpe i think when we put await that time database call happens, so it will always call first call then wait and then the second call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are not the same.

The first will initialize a Promise, *wait for it to complete*, then initialize another Promise, and wait for the second Promise to complete.

The second will initialize both Promises at once and wait for *both* to complete. So, it will take less time. Here's a similar example:

```js
// Takes twice as long as the other:

const makeProm = () => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));

console.log('start');
(async () => {
  const foo = await makeProm();
  const bar = await makeProm();
  console.log('done');
})();
```

```js
// Takes half as long as the other:

const makeProm = () => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));

console.log('start');
(async () => {
  const fooProm = makeProm();
  const barProm = makeProm();
  const foo = await fooProm;
  const bar = await barProm;
  console.log('done');
})();
```

But you might consider making the code even clearer with `Promise.all` instead:

```
const [fixtures, team] = await Promise.all([
  fixtureModel.fetchAll(),
  teamModel.fetch(teamId)
]);
```

Comment: I think when we put await that time, it will actually call for database right?

Comment: What do you mean? It sounds like `.fetchAll` and `.fetch` already return Promises

Comment: @BinitGhetiya Putting `await` later does not mean database call will happen later. `await` will do just one thing thats **wait to resolve the returned promise**

Comment: Ok got it from your code snippet, in first style, it will wait for a response then the second call happens, but it second call both calls go parallel and we got a response

Comment: @ambianBeing undrestood now, before i thought it will call database only when we put await or use then(res=> {})

Comment: When you see a function invocation which calls a function which returns a Promise, that Promise will have been initialized *then*. `await` and `.then` only change the control flow of what happens when the Promise resolves

Comment: Yes, now I understand when I used () that time database call was already done and returned promise just to get data from that promise we used await or then.